# Sending and Receiving 2D Arrays java

Tags: java, networking

What I would like to achieve by asking this question is to learn how to send and receive *2-Dimensional Arrays* to another computer.

The context is that the *2-D Array* is the map for my game, and when I start my game, I would like an option to be a server or client(if client, specify the server *IP*) and then the server would send the client (One of which would be another person, with a different *IP*) the 2D array when they connect.

I hope this all makes sense, I have given this ago but I couldn't get it working, I have tried with *Datagram Packets*, but I couldn't figure out how to send all the 2D array in segments, and then turn it back into a 2D array.

What type of Stream or general networking object do I need to use? And will it be-able to send the 2D array?
Can you give an example to help me set it up?

Also to note, I will afterwards be sending Player Coordinates and Map Changes, so If the Networking object works with that too, then that's a plus.

Comment: A 2D array of what? Google for "Java Serialization".

Comment: [Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/overview) would be a nice fit for structure passing...

Comment: @ricintech... great... u edited it nicely.

Answer (score 2):

This will work with any primitive type arrays and Object arrays if object type is instanceof Serializable

server

```
    ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(port);
    Socket s = ss.accept();
    ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
    byte[][] array = (byte[][])is.readObject();
```

client

```
    byte[][] array = new byte[10][10];
    Socket s = new Socket("host", port);
    ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
    os.writeObject(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create an object out of it. It´s easier to handle afterwards.
After that you serialize it, then you split it in smaller byte[] (if it´s bigger then 64 kb).
You add some bytes to each packet, I prefer
byte[0] = is splited?
byte[1] + byte[2] = sendNumber (just for controlling, it increases after every sent object)
byte[3] = how many parts your object has
byte[4] = what part is it
What you need else.
Afterwards you can easily put the parts together.
I have never used it but i also found a library know as kryonet (while googling).
Have a look... google it properly.