# How to read/write a 2d char array through a Socket?

Tags: java, arrays, sockets, io, char

So I am writing a game of LAN tic-tac-toe. I have the "board" stored as a 2 dimensional `char` array. I want to be able to send and receive this array through Sockets. I am currently using a `InputStream` and `OutputStream` to send single bytes. However, I don't think this will work for sending the array. Also, these streams only seem capable of sending `int` type data. Can someone please explain to me how too send 2 dimensional `char` arrays over sockets using I/O streams. Example code would be great! Thanks.

**Current Code:**

```
public void communicate() {
    try {
        OutputStream os = client.getOutputStream();
        InputStream is = client.getInputStream();
    }

    while (gameOver == false) {
        char[][] board = new char[3][3];
        try {
            os.write(board); //this dosen't work, only sends non-array int types. 
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: You need to serialize your objects or use XML, JSON, or any other string-based format.

Comment: @PM77-1 well, I do hope that isn't the only way because I don't know how to use XML or JSON. Are you sure? This honestly seems like a relatively simple task that Java should be able to handle alone. I could always convert the char array into some other type of array like String or int then when its recieved on the other end, I could change it back.

Comment: `Array` is an object.  If you use serialization, Java will create string representation of your objects for you. See [Storing and Reading Objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jndi/objects/store.html)

Comment: @PM77-1 ah, okay thanks, I get it, also found this in the meantime: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14054828/sending-and-receiving-2d-arrays-java. Could you write me an example code though? It would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java `InputStream` and `OutputStream` classes only deal with reading and writing `byte(s)`. You can certainly use write your character array as bytes using just input and output streams.

```
public static char[][] readBoard(InputStream in) throws IOException {
    char[][] board = new char[3][3];
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++) {
        board[i/3][i%3] = (char) in.read();
    }
    return board;
}

public static void writeBoard(OutputStream out, char[][] board) throws IOException {
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++) {
        out.write(board[i/3][i%3]);
    }
}
```

You could also use the `ObjectOutputStream` and `ObjectInputStream` to read and write objects through streams. Note that classes read and written to these streams must implement the `Serializable` interface (your `char[][]` will work).

```
public static char[][] readBoard(InputStream in) throws IOException {
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(in);
    return (char[][]) ois.readObject();
}

public static void writeBoard(OutputStream out, char[][] board) throws IOException {
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(out);
    oos.writeObject(board);
}
```

Comment: Okay this is exactly what I was looking for. Also @PM 77-1 thank you, I think you were saying the same thing. I'm probably going to go with the 2nd way because it seems a bit cleaner that individually sending/recieving each byte of the array. Btw, +1 for clever use of the single for loop of the 2D array. I always used 2 nested for loops in the past for 2D arrays.