# 2D Double array to byte array

Tags: java, arrays, server, client, byte

So I was wondering if there was any way to turn a 2d double(or int) array into a 2d byte array and vice versa.

I want to have a list of variables(like player info and AI position and animations for both) to be sent over a Datagram socket and I looked around but couldn't find an answer.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert double to byte\[\] array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13071777/convert-double-to-byte-array)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of dealing with difficult conversions, you should **serialize** the array, then send it through the socket and **deserialize** it again. You can do so with an `ObjectInputStream` and an `ObjectOutputStream` as presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14054828/sending-and-receiving-2d-arrays-java) or use any other serialization library.

Comment: @talex You are right. This is just a **simple** way, if OP is a beginner. Nevertheless, I would recommend a specialized library for this, if the criteria is performance.